# Credential-connect to project server 2016

Tags: development, 2016, .net, credentials

I get an error in the`context.ExecuteQuery();`line while trying to connect to the server.

```
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your username for PWA");
        userName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your password for PWA");
        passWord = Console.ReadLine();


        NetworkCredential netcred = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
        SharePointOnlineCredentials orgIDCredential = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(netcred.UserName, netcred.SecurePassword);
        context.Credentials = orgIDCredential;
```

The error ist

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequestException: 'The IDCRL response header from server 'http://xxx.xxx.de/' is not valid. The response header value is 'NTLM'.

If i use `context.Credentials = netcred;`
I get a different error

> System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized'.

But I am authorized.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929259/authenticate-network-credential-to-access-sharepoint-site-on-client-object-model), here had the same problem, don't forget to **use domain** before loginname and don't use *SharePointOnlineCredentials* when you are connecting to SP2016.

You should use something like this (from the post):

```
string _siteURL = "https://intranet.co.uk";
NetworkCredential _myCredentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "https://intranet");
ClientContext _clientContext = new ClientContext(_siteURL);
_clientContext.Credentials = _myCredentials;
Web _MyWebSite = _clientContext.Web;
```

*Hope it helps!*

Comment: I tried it, but I got a different error. "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: 'Cannot find stub for type with id "{154360b4-899f-4237-b0ed-3e35f014c748}". The specified server may not support APIs used in this operation.'"

Comment: Have you tried classic SP commandlets? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/get-spsite?view=sharepoint-ps